# “Comparison method violates its general contract!”

Tags: java

I have googled some same question and I know the reason.However the crash happened only once so I come here to ask you what may lead to crash.

```
    Collections.sort(downloadTasks, new Comparator<DownloadTask>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(DownloadTask lhs, DownloadTask rhs) {
            if (lhs == null || rhs == null) return 0;
            return (int) (lhs.mTaskInfo.time - rhs.mTaskInfo.time);
        }
    });
```

The error is :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract! at java.util.TimSort.mergeHi(TimSort.java:864)
>     at java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(TimSort.java:481)
>     at java.util.TimSort.mergeCollapse(TimSort.java:406)
>     at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:210)
>     at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:169)
>     at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:2010)
>     at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:1883)

As you see, I compare two objects by their `time` member. The `time` is `long` type.

I think the crash may be from:

- **Whether does converting long to int lead to crash?**
- **if (lhs == null || rhs == null) return 0;** But theoretically lhs and rhs neither is null.

## EDIT

If `lhs` and `rhs` can be null , what should I do ?

## EDIT For Android

In Android, `Long.compare()` requires API 19. You can do this under API 19 :

```
public static int compare(long lhs, long rhs) {
    return lhs < rhs ? -1 : (lhs == rhs ? 0 : 1);
}
```

Comment: What crash? What error do you get, when, with what code, what happens, what do you expect to happen? Take a look at [ask]

Comment: As the title says the error is `Comparison method violates its general contract!`

Comment: Can you explain why the cast leads to crash? @Thilo

Comment: I agree with you. Can you write your answer?

Comment: Try casting before subtracting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both these cases are problematic.

> `if (lhs == null || rhs == null) return 0;`

If you have `[123, null, 234]`, then you compare `123` as equal to `null`, `null` as equal to `234`, and by transitivity you should get `123` equals `234`. But that is not what your comparator returns.

The solution here would be to either disallow `null` or sort all `nulls` to the bottom (or top), i.e. only return `0` is *both* are `null`, otherwise return `1` or `-1` (depending on the `null` being left or right).

> return (int) (lhs.mTaskInfo.time - rhs.mTaskInfo.time);

Consider comparing `Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1` to `0`. The difference between the two is `Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1`. Casting this to `int` wraps to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.  The opposite comparison should then give you `- Integer.MIN_VALUE`, but [that is `Integer.MIN_VALUE` again due to overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12535130/14955).

The solution here is to use `Long.compare(a,b)`.

Answer (score 2):

The "general contract" of the comparison method is well documented in the javadoc of the [`compare(T o1, T o2)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-) method:

> The implementor must ensure that `sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x))` for all `x` and `y`. (This implies that `compare(x, y)` must throw an exception if and only if `compare(y, x)` throws an exception.)
>
> The implementor must also ensure that the relation is transitive: `((compare(x, y)>0) && (compare(y, z)>0))` implies `compare(x, z)>0`.
>
> Finally, the implementor must ensure that `compare(x, y)==0` implies that `sgn(compare(x, z))==sgn(compare(y, z))` for all z.

So, which of these 3 rules are you violating? **All 3**

First rule is violated because `time` is a `long`, so `(int) (lhs.mTaskInfo.time - rhs.mTaskInfo.time)` can be equal to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. If you flip the two parameters to `compare()`, the result would still be `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, because an `int` value cannot store the negated value.

The second rule is violated because `int` overflows. Since `time` is `long`, I'll assume they contain standard millisecond values, and an `int` can only store values up to **24 days**. So let's say input is `Jan 1, Jan 15, Jan 30`. `compare(Jan 1, Jan 15)` is +14 days, and `compare(Jan 15, Jan 30)` is +15 days, but `compare(Jan 1, Jan 30)` should be +29 days, but it overflows are returns something like -19 days. Oops!!!!

The third rule is violated because of the bad null checks. Let's say input is `null, Jan 1, Jan 2`. `compare(null, Jan 1)` is 0, and so is `compare(null, Jan 2)`, but `compare(Jan 1, Jan 2)` is +1 day.

*Solution*

The `int` overflow and `MIN_VALUE` issues can be easily fixed by using [`Long.compare(long x, long y)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#compare-long-long-).

For the `null` issue, you need to decide if nulls should sort first or last. The following will sort nulls first:

```
public int compare(DownloadTask lhs, DownloadTask rhs) {
    if (lhs == null) {
        if (rhs == null)
            return 0;
        return -1;
    }
    if (rhs == null)
        return 1;
    return Long.compare(lhs.mTaskInfo.time, rhs.mTaskInfo.time);
}
```

Or the single-statement version:

```
public int compare(DownloadTask lhs, DownloadTask rhs) {
    return (lhs == null ? (rhs == null ? 0 : -1)
            : (rhs == null ? 1 : Long.compare(lhs.mTaskInfo.time, rhs.mTaskInfo.time)));
}
```

Comment: Awesome and clear answer. Thanks very much.